# Two Separate Networks, Use one Internet Connection Only

Tags: networking

A client of mine has two internet connections and a router for each to handle these connections. One of the routers serves the LAN for the entire office while the other router is used for wireless connectivity.

A particular user needs to connect to the LAN for access to the office shares and printers etc. But this user also wants to connect to the internet via the wireless router because the internet connection is faster and more stable. The computer has both LAN and WiFi adapters so connecting to each of the networks is not a problem.

The question: How can I force the only internet connection to be used would be that via the wireless router connection and still allow the user to access the shares and printers etc on the LAN via the wired connection?

I have looked into network bridging in Windows but this doesn't seem to isolate the internet connection but rather try to use both to increase speed...not what I am looking for.

Thank you

Comment: My apologies and thank you for the clarification. I will use Server Fault from now on regarding networking questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to to tweak the windows routing table.

Once connected to both networks, delete the default routes that windows adds, then add a route to the LAN using the wired interface, and set the wireless router as the default gateway.

If the LAN is 192.168.0.0/24, and the wireless router is 192.168.0.1 it should be something like this:

`route add 192.168.0.0 mask 255.255.255.0 0.0.0.0 interface Local Area Connection`

`route add 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 192.168.0.1 interface <Wifi Nic name here>`

Answer (score -1):

I assume your router IPs;
192.168.1.1 --wireless router
192.168.1.2 -- office internet router

192.168.1.1 should have DHCP enable
192.168.1.2 should have DHCP disable

connect both routers direct or using switch.

Comment: Hmmm, I still need the rest of the users to have access to the internet via the wired router; IP address 192.168.1.2 in your case. Wouldn't they need the gateway to be set to this same IP? If I set it up as you outline wouldn't ALL users essentially have internet access through the wireless router since that is the DHCP server?